# import matplotlib error in snakemake-tutorial environment

Tags: python, matplotlib, snakemake

I am trying to get familiar with snakemake and started with the [tutorial](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/basics.html#). All works fine until Step 6: Using custom scripts. Apparently the python code crashes when importing matplotlib.

I run the following command in the tutorial home folder:

```
snakemake
```

And get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/scratch/users/xxx/snakemake/tutorial/.snakemake/scripts/tmpfg_qprf9.plot-quals.py", line 5, in <module>
import matplotlib
File "/home/xxx/tools/miniconda3/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
from . import cbook, rcsetup
File "/home/xxx/tools/miniconda3/envs/snakemake-tutorial/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
import numpy as np
File "/n/sw/centos6/numpy-1.7.1_python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
from version import git_revision as __git_revision__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'
```

In my understanding the idea is to provide an environment where everything is setup. And indeed `conda list` shows `matplotlib 2.2.3` is installed. I assume I do something wrong, as I could not find any other user asking this question, however, I also failed in solving it myself. Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To me that looks like an error on importing git_revision

Comment: Thx Rashid. So how can I fix that? Git 2.9.0 is currently set up in my environment.

Comment: It seems the numpy version that is imported by matplotlib comes from a totally different python environment. You are using python 3.6 from conda to import matplotlib, but numpy comes from a python 2.7 environment.